# How works the function round_xn_over_d from pdftex.web?

Tags: tex-core

The function `round_xn_over_d` takes scaled point value as the argument and returns scaled point value. Its meaning is as follows:

Suppose we have `\mydimen=10truept`. As we know, if `\magnification` is used, "true" dimensions are unmagnified (see p.60 in *TeXbook*). Using `round_xn_over_d` on TeX's internal representation of `\mydimen` gives the same value as `\mydimen` would have had if `\magnification` had not been used.

Here is the simplified version (`x` - the argument - is supposed to be positive) of the body of the `round_xn_over_d` function (written in *C* language):

```c
int n = mag;
int d = 1000;
unsigned int t, u, v;
t = (x % 0100000) * n;
u = (x / 0100000) * n + (t / 0100000);
v = (u % d) * 0100000 + (t % 0100000);
/* it is supposed that u/d < 0100000 */
u = 0100000 * (u/d) + (v/d);
v = v % d;
if (2*v >= d)
  incr(u);
return u;
```

How does it work?

Comment: I forgot to answer the main part: the point is simply to compute `x * mag / 1000` without arithmetic overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Verbose answer, thinking as I typed. Will try to write a shorter version later.)

`0100000` means octal `100000` i.e. 8<sup>5</sup> = 2<sup>15</sup> = 32768. So let's look at the code snippet from the question, with `0100000` replaced with `32768` as we're all less familiar with octal today. And we can leave out the specific values of `n` and `d`: they don't matter except maybe we assume `0 <= n < 32768` and `0 <= d`:

```c
unsigned int t, u, v;
t = (x % 32768) * n;
u = (x / 32768) * n + (t / 32768);
v = (u % d) * 32768 + (t % 32768);
/* it is supposed that u/d < 32768 */
u = 32768 * (u/d) + (v/d);
v = v % d;
if (2*v >= d)
  incr(u);
return u;
```

Let's write the integer `x` as `a*32768 + b` where `a = x/32768` and `b = x % 32768`. Then the code snippet becomes:

```c
unsigned int t, u, v;
t = b * n;
u = a * n + (t / 32768);
v = (u % d) * 32768 + (t % 32768);
/* it is supposed that u/d < 32768 */
u = 32768 * (u/d) + (v/d);
v = v % d;
if (2*v >= d)
  incr(u);
return u;
```

To understand this further, consider this:

```
        32768s place    units place
x            a              b
x*n         a*n            b*n      (multiply both components by n)
x*n         a*n             t       (definition of t)
x*n     a*n + t/32768     t%32768   (normalize, i.e. "carry" to the 32768s place)
x*n          u            t%32768   (definition of u)
```

So far we have multiplied `x` by `n`. Next we want to divide by `d`. We can do it the way we usually do long division:

```
        32768s place    units place
x*n          u            t%32768            (from earlier)
→ divide the first component by d, and shift the remainder:
            u/d     (u%d)*32768 + (t%32768)
            u/d              v               (definition of v)
→ also divide the unit's component by d:
            u/d             v/d,   with remainder v%d
```

Reading this result as a number gives the quotient. To avoid possible confusion from reusing variables, let's tweak the line of code and call the quotient and remainder `uu` and `vv` instead of `u` and `v`:

```c
/* it is supposed that u/d < 32768 */
uu = 32768 * (u/d) + (v/d);
vv = v % d;
```

Finally the rounding: `uu` above is the quotient (integer part of the division), but if the remainder (`vv`) happens to be larger than half of `d`, then it means we should round up:

```c
if (2*vv >= d)
  incr(uu);
```

We can now return the result:

```c
return uu;
```

We never had to use the fact that `x` happens to be a scaled value actually; the function works even if `x` is thought of as an integer. The point of this code is just to compute the value `x * n / d`, rounded correctly, without ever causing any result to exceed 32768 × 32768 = 2<sup>30</sup>.

---

In other words: suppose we're given three integers `x`, `n` and `d`, which are all guaranteed to be less than 2<sup>30</sup> (and `n` less than 32768), and we want to compute the value of `x * n / d` (half-integer rounded up), without ever exceeding the value `2^30`. This is what we'd do.

Comment: It turns out that `round_xn_over_d` is essentially identical to §107 in `tex.web`. The difference is that `xn_over_d` uses *remainder*. Is there any reason for preferring `round_xn_over_d` to `xn_over_d` in `s := round_xn_over_d(s, mag, 1000);` in `pdftex.web`? (it seems logical that if for calculating "true" dimensions `xn_over_d` is used, then for the inverse operation the same procedure should be used)